# Is there another way to reference non-static content?

Tags: java, android, static, non-static

Well let me say that the program works, sort of. Since I was trying to reference `CheckScores` from static content I did this:

```
 ScoringActivity scoringActivity = new ScoringActivity();
 scoringActivity.CheckScores(etEnteredScores.getText().toString());
```

Now this is inside of `public static class ScoringFragment extends Fragment` which is in the same `.class` as the `Activity`.

Which I thought worked at first but after looking at the overkill amount of logs I have in that method it turns out it does not.

`requiredAmount` is the max amount of score which is set by the user and stores in a SQL db.

Here is the `logcat`:

```
02-05 23:58:42.720    3492-3492/com.test.app V/required Count﹕ 6 <-Straight from SQL table
02-05 23:58:42.720    3492-3492/com.test.app V/required Count﹕ 6 <-From the variable after I assign it.
02-05 23:58:54.606    3492-3492/com.test.app V/requiredAmount﹕ 0 <-From the first Log.v in CheckScores after calling new
02-05 23:58:54.606    3492-3492/com.test.app V/userScores﹕ 5 <-Just me spliting it into an array
02-05 23:58:54.606    3492-3492/com.test.app V/userScores﹕ [5] <-Checking if it split right
02-05 23:58:54.606    3492-3492/com.test.app V/Mismatch﹕ You have 1 scores. Acceptable amount is 0 <-As figured its 0 instead of 6
```

CheckScores method(inside `ScoringActivity.class`)

```
public void CheckScores(String userScores) {
    String[] scoresArray;

    Log.v("requiredAmount", Integer.toString(requiredCount));

    // ^ Match with beginning of line | [0-9] Allow 0-9 | , Allow comma | + Match one or more | $ Match End of line
    if (userScores.matches("^[0-9,]+$")) {

        if (userScores.charAt(0) == ',') {
            // If it does parse and substring to remove them
            // otherwise the following regex leaves one , behind
            int i = 0;
            while (!Character.isDigit(userScores.charAt(i))) i++;
            int j = userScores.length();
            userScores = userScores.substring(i, j);
        }

        // (.) Match any character) | \1 If it is followed by itself | + Match one or more | $1 replace by the first captured char.
        userScores = userScores.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");

        Log.v("userScores", userScores);

        // Split at the ',' and put each number in it's own cell in the array
        scoresArray = userScores.split(",");
        Log.v("userScores", Arrays.toString(scoresArray));

        // Check if scoresArray is equal to maxScores
        if (scoresArray.length == requiredCount) {
            int[] uiArray = new int[scoresArray.length];

            // Parse String[] into int[]
            for (int i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
                try {
                    uiArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(scoresArray[i]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { // If triple checking isn't enough...
                }
            }
            Log.v("uiArray(int)", Arrays.toString(uiArray));

            // Add up all elements in uiArray
            for (int j = 0; j < uiArray.length; j++) {
                sum += uiArray[j];
            }
            comformedScores = uiArray;
            Log.v("Accepted","Scores sum:" + sum + " Number of scores:" + uiArray.length + " Number of ends:" + uiArray.length / 6);
        } else {
            Log.v("Mismatch", "You have " + scoresArray.length + " scores. Acceptable amount is " + requiredCount);
        }
    } else {
        Log.v("Mismatch","Invalid Input. (Only #'s and ,'s allowed)");
    }
}
```

You can see that I check `requiredAmount` as soon as the method is called. `requiredAmount` is the max number of scores the user is allowed to have. Now I check this variable before and it is grabbing it from the SQL table with no problems.

What I think is happening is the when I call `new ScoringActivity()` it resets all of the variables. Is there any other way to pass the data through the `CheckScores` method?

If you need any more information please feel free to ask. I might not answer right away though but I will try to get back as quick as possible.

Comment: `new ScoringActivity()` doesn't reset any variables... it just creates another ScoringActivity with default variables. The old one is still there, but you're accessing the new one, which of course doesn't have anything set yet because you just created it.

Comment: On a side note, you really should not create an activity like this. You should never `new` an activity, but to only start it using `startActivity()`.

Comment: OMG you should not create (`new`) activities yourself, Android will do it for you. This is why you have _onCreate()_.

Comment: If I don't `new` the activity it can't call `CheckScores` because it non-static content in a static class